# Pandas dataframe to_csv escape double quotes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, escaping, double-quotes

I am trying to export pandas dataframe in csv. Some of data contains double quotes and I can't get it escaped properly.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':'some text'}, {'c1':11,'c2':'some "text"'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
output = StringIO()
df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', escapechar='\b', header=False, index=False)
```

as result I get double quotes which are escaped with another double quotes:

```
'10\tsome text\n11\t"some ""text"""\n'
```

but I need it to be:

```
'10\tsome text\n11\t"some \x08"text\x08""\n'
```

I tried different combinations of doublequote, quotechar and quoting arguments for to_csv() function but no luck.
Closest I got is:

```
df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', escapechar='\b', header=False, index=False, doublequote=False)
```

which results in properly escaped double quotes but the whole cell is not wrapped in double quotes and thus cannot be parsed correctly on further steps

```
'10\tsome text\n11\tsome \x08"text\x08"\n'
```

Is there a way to make pandas escape double quotes with needed escape character?

PS. Currently I have only workaround to replace "" with \x08" manually in string buffer

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this issue with following settings.

```
df.to_csv(output, sep="\t", escapechar="\\", header=False, index=False, doublequote=False)
```

`escapechar="\\"` will put a single back-slash with the double quotes in your value as you have already specified `doublequote=False`, which will make sure double-quotes are note escaped with another double-quote.

Comment: I had texts with double quotes in them, this leaded to they were escaped with slash /. So this text: 'hello with "quotes" here' leaded to 'hello with /"quotes/" here'. Without your solution i orignally got this text (since escapechar was doublequotes: '"hello with ""quotes"" here"' (note the extra double quotes at the very beginning and the very end. I solved this by changing the quotechar="'" so I no get this text: 'hello with "quotes" here'